# xfce windows sometimes get "stuck" and I can't open them from taskbar

Tags: xfce

Although the window is a simple terminal shell with no running task, I can't open it by clicking on it, or even right click close. Is there a way to open it ? It does not happen with all windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this a few times. Somehow the window becomes both maximised and 0x0 pixels. You press [Alt] + [space], you get the menu of that window, even if you cannot see it. You then select 'Unmaximise', do it again, and select 'Maximise'.